# sending smtp mail in yii

Tags: php, email, yii, smtp

I have an online leave application form which i have some fields and i can create,view and modify that leave form. I also want to do one more thing. whatever values am giving for all those fields like leave type,number of days, reason etc. Just i want to fetch all those values  and i want to send it in mail.. In create form i will give values for all the fields.. When i click create button it should send an email with those details..

Here is my controller code for actionCreate. Here i have doubt in this line =>$mailmsg = (array('id'=>$model->leave_id));

```
public function actionCreate()
   {
    $model=new EmpLeave;
            $model->dateof_leave = date("Y-m-d H:i");
    if(isset($_POST['EmpLeave']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['EmpLeave'];
        if($model->save())
                        $recipients = "sridhar.venkatesan53@gmail.com";
                        $headers["From"] = "noreply@elixir.in";
                        $headers["To"] = "sridhar.venkatesan53@gmail.com";
                        $headers["Subject"] = "User feedback";
                        $mailmsg = (array('id'=>$model->leave_id));
                        /* SMTP server name, port, user/passwd */
                        $smtpinfo["host"] = "smtp.mandrillapp.com";
                        $smtpinfo["port"] = "587";
                        $smtpinfo["auth"] = true;
                        $smtpinfo["username"] = "noreply@elixir.in";
                        $smtpinfo["password"] = "oNkeBOEA5MfaN_24loUs1w";
                        /* Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method */
                        $mail_object =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo);
                        /* Ok send mail */
                        $mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $mailmsg);
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->leave_id));
    }
    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

This is my view.php

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    'leave_id',
    'leave_type',
    'leave_reason',
    'numof_days',
    'type',
            'dateof_leave',
   ),
 )); ?>
```

Comment: Downvoted for copying code from elsewhere without understanding and expecting others to solve your problems. Your comments in the other answers show you did not use any extension, but have build code for the Mail factory class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget about {}

```
if($model->save()){
    .....
}
```

Comment: In that if condition we are just rendering the view page..But i dont know the flow of save() and where we defined that method..

Comment: This method defined in ActiveRecord class, that extend all model. EmpLeave is CActiveRecord?

Comment: leave_id is a primary key? so i can be used only if model is successfuly validated and saved to database, so all this code must be in {}

Comment: Yes i understood...now i want to fetch all the values and have to send with the mail... can i code like this ?                                  $mailmsg = $REQUEST['leave_type'].$REQUEST['leave_reason'].$REQUEST['numof_days'].$REQUEST['dateof_leave'];

Comment: include(Mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.....am facing this error.

Answer (score 1):

You want to send Inputed values as Mail . Your message body look like a array . its processed as string or html before sending.

`$mailmsg /*variable you are try to send as array .probably it must be string`

```
$mailmsg=(array('id'=>$model->leave_id))  /*just try this for your own testing after you get idea about this*/
echo "<pre>";
print_r($mailmsg);
exit();
```

code for change the post values from form to message text

```
$mailmsg="<div><ul>";
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
     $mailmsg.="<li>".$key." - ".$value."</li>";     // String Generated 
}
$mailmsg.="</ul></div>";
```

That $mailmsg contain the data's of your form inputs in html formated string

```
  public function actionCreate()
   {
    $model=new EmpLeave;
            $model->dateof_leave = date("Y-m-d H:i");
    if(isset($_POST['EmpLeave']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['EmpLeave'];
        if($model->save())
{
                        require_once(Yii::app()->basePath.'/extensions/PearMail/Mail-1.2.0/Mail.php');


                        $recipients = "sridhar.venkatesan53@gmail.com";
                        $headers["From"] = "noreply@elixir.in";
                        $headers["To"] = "sridhar.venkatesan53@gmail.com";
                        $headers["Subject"] = "User feedback";
                        $mailmsg="<div><ul>";
                        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
                        {
                             $mailmsg.="<li>".$key." - ".$value."</li>";     
                        }
                        $mailmsg.="</ul></div>";
                        /* SMTP server name, port, user/passwd */
                        $smtpinfo["host"] = "smtp.mandrillapp.com";
                        $smtpinfo["port"] = "587";
                        $smtpinfo["auth"] = true;
                        $smtpinfo["username"] = "noreply@elixir.in";
                        $smtpinfo["password"] = "oNkeBOEA5MfaN_24loUs1w";
                        /* Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method */
                        $mail_object =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo);
                        /* Ok send mail */
                        $mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $mailmsg);
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->leave_id));
    }
    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Comment: @alexk984 how can i assign the inputed values to $mailmsg in html format..can you give example?

Comment: yes i tried..but it shows this error -> include(Mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.                     $mail_object =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo);                      whether the above line is correct or not? just i got it from tutorial..@ Ryan Babu, @alexk984

Comment: You need to insert file mail.php as 3rd party file You just go through this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/17644-include-3rd-party-library-pear-mail/)

Comment: Which type of mailer you are using here. Any extensions you installed

Comment: Try to use phpmailer extension on yii. You are called the mailer function Mail::factory need the support file mail.php.  go to yii extension page search the extension phpmailer your problem will solved

Comment: @Sridhar, you cannot just copy code from somewhere and expect it to work. Please go back to your original source of the code and read properly how the Mail factory is built into the code.

Comment: yes i have downloaded PHPMailer extension and copied in my extension folder.i have also added one more code require 'class.PHPMailer.php'. still am facing the error -> require(class.PHPMailer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.@crafter yes i copied the code from some sources. But i would like to understand everything. Specially i want to understand the relation between the Mail::factory and extension which i included PHPMailer.php. please guide me. @Ryan Babu,@Alex.

Comment: @Sridhar can you please edit your question . Update the action in question .

Comment: dont panic by this issue its a simple dependency error . you are missing the library file for SMTP .

Comment: you dont need include any file while using the phpmailer extension its already configured correctly . find the usage or docs in yii extension page

Answer (score 1):

This code is enough for send  . you just replace your details and msg body

```
Yii::import('application.extensions.phpmailer.JPhpMailer');
$mail = new JPhpMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smpt.163.com';     // your host and smtp address
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'yourname@163.com';      //login username
$mail->Password = 'yourpassword';          //login password
$mail->SetFrom('yourname@163.com', 'yourname');   //from 
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication';
$mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';
$mail->MsgHTML('<h1>JUST A TEST!</h1>');
$mail->AddAddress('john.doe@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
$status=$mail->Send();
print_r($status);
```

Comment: you are importing JPhpMailer and phpmailer which are under the extension folder right

Comment: Yes correct its under the extensions folder [the extension files here](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/phpmailer/)

Comment: the above code is not showing any error. but mail is not received.

Comment: you need to configure . and try to print the status of message send. If you are run in locally your system smtp must be enable